# Filter Apache Error Logs in Logstash using grok

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I need to filter apache error logs using  grok.
Please help me with the pattern I am not able to create!.

My sample log :

```
2020-10-07T01:21:26.403-0400    ERROR   [reload]        cfgfile/list.go:96  Error creating runner from config: Error getting config for fileset system/auth: Error interpreting the template of the inp$
2020-10-07T01:21:36.404-0400    ERROR   [reload]        cfgfile/list.go:96  Error creating runner from config: Error getting config for fileset system/auth: Error interpreting the template of the inp$
2020-10-07T01:21:38.925-0400    ERROR   pipeline/output.go:100  Failed to connect to backoff(async(tcp://IP:5044)): dial tcp IP:5044: i/o timeout
2020-10-07T01:21:38.925-0400    INFO    pipeline/output.go:93   Attempting to reconnect to backoff(async(tcp://IP:5044)) with 26743 reconnect attempt(s)
2020-10-07T01:21:38.925-0400    INFO    [publish]   pipeline/retry.go:189   retryer: send unwait-signal to consumer
2020-10-07T01:21:38.925-0400    INFO    [publish]   pipeline/retry.go:191     done
2020-10-07T01:21:38.925-0400    INFO    [publish]   pipeline/retry.go:166   retryer: send wait signal to consumer
2020-10-07T01:21:38.925-0400    INFO    [publish]   pipeline/retry.go:168     done
```

I understand through grok patterns, we can use these below, but I am not understanding how to use this in Grok Pattern:

```
# Error logs
HTTPD20_ERRORLOG \[%{HTTPDERROR_DATE:timestamp}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] (?:\[client %{IPORHOST:clientip}\] ){0,1}%{GREEDYDATA:message}
HTTPD24_ERRORLOG \[%{HTTPDERROR_DATE:timestamp}\] \[%{WORD:module}:%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\] \[pid %{POSINT:pid}(:tid %{NUMBER:tid})?\]( \(%{POSINT:proxy_errorcode}\)%{DATA:proxy_message}:)?( \[client %{IPORHOST:clientip}:%{POSINT:clientport}\])?( %{DATA:errorcode}:)? %{GREEDYDATA:message}
HTTPD_ERRORLOG %{HTTPD20_ERRORLOG}|%{HTTPD24_ERRORLOG}
```

Can anyone please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add log samples to your question.

Comment: Which version of logstash do you use?

Comment: @karanshah added the sample logs.

Comment: @YLR I am using logstash 7.9.2

Answer (score 0):

After work on your sample data this grok pattern must work :

```
filter {
    grok {
            match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL}(%{SPACE}\[%{WORD:action}\])?%{SPACE}%{WORD:package}/%{WORD:class}.go:%{INT:line:number}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:message}$" }
    }
}
```

Your data are not exactly http, so a custom pattern needed, I guess my grok must be more easy to read without space, I recommand to you to use mutate-gsub to uniformize space (be carreful with your final sentence named "message" in my solution).

You have more details about this pattern and other [here](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-patterns-core/blob/master/patterns/httpd).

Comment: So  to filter error logs can i use :
match => { "message" => "%{HTTPD20_ERRORLOG}" } ?

Comment: You can try pattern here : http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Comment: HTTPD20_ERRORLOG does not match the log samples shared in the questions. The filter pattern suggested by @ylr should work.